# Add spaces in Beautifoulsuop parsing HTML .text python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm parsing some HTML data and im trying to parse text, but when I'm not getting the desired result.

HTML Snippets of what I'm parsing:

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
<p class="elementor-image-box-description">Online Raffle<br/>Shipping<br/>Closes 28/05<br/><br/></p>
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
<p class="elementor-image-box-description">Online Release<br/>Shipping<br/>More Info here<br/><br/></p>
```

**EXAMPLE 3**

```
<p class="elementor-image-box-description">Instagram Raffle<br/>Collection (Hong Kong)<br/>Closes 05/28<br/><br/></p>
```

Code I'm using to parse:

```
info = div.find('p').text
```

Output per example:

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
Online RaffleShippingCloses 28/05
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
Online ReleaseShippingMore Info here
```

**EXAMPLE 3**

```
Instagram RaffleCollection (Hong Kong)Closes 05/28
```

Expected Output:

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
Online Raffle Shipping Closes 28/05
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
Online Release Shipping More Info here
```

**EXAMPLE 3**

```
Instagram Raffle Collection (Hong Kong) Closes 05/28
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import re

with open('a.html', 'r') as filee:
  temp = filee.read()
  s = re.sub('<br/>', ' ', temp)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
  for temp_p in soup.find_all("p"):
    print(temp_p.text)

#Online Raffle Shipping Closes 28/05  
#Online Release Shipping More Info here  
#Instagram Raffle Collection (Hong Kong) Closes 05/28
```

I just used re to replace `<br/>` with space and then ran the program

Answer (score 0):

For `EXAMPLE 1`, The simplest way is to replace `info = div.find('p').text` with `info = soup.find('p').getText(separator=u' ')` you can try it:

```
html_doc = """<p class="elementor-image-box-description">Online Raffle<br/>Shipping<br/>Closes 28/05<br/><br/></p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

info = soup.find('p').getText(separator=u' ')

print(info)

print(info)
```

Output:

```
Online Raffle Shipping Closes 28/05
```

The same has to be done for the others.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to replace `info = div.find('p').text`
with `info = soup.find('p').get_text(separator=' ')`.

I tried it in my localhost with your example one. This is how I did it.
Python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import *
page = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1/bs.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
info = soup.find('p').get_text(separator=' ')
print(info)
```

Output:

```
Online Raffle Shipping Closes 28/05
```